# Help figuring out how to build for the iOS Unit3D

Tags: iphone, unity, ios

So currently I'm exporting my game strictly for testing to the iOS (iPad.)

I don't own a Mac, so I'm having my client make a build from his Mac, but that means I need very specific instructions for him as he isn't very tech-savvy. I've looked online and can't find much at all about what all you need to export from Unity and make a file for the iOS, then sync it to your iPad. Could anyone provide a video or and help at all for this?

Thanks,

Tim.

Comment: Is your client enrolled in the Apple Developer program? Does he have XCode installed? These are two prerequisites to compile a Unity app for iOS... You should really get a Mac if you want to develop for iOS. Testing builds via your client seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: It is a very bad idea, I'm purchasing a Mac shortly. To make things easier. I know he has an Apple Developer account, but I'm not sure if he has XCode.

Comment: Honestly I would say don't even try. There are too many fiddly intricacies that you need to be dealing with hands-on. Just bump up your plans to purchase a Mac; a Mac Mini is perfect for developing an iOS game and costs considerably less than a professional iOS license for Unity. You can use your current monitor, keyboard, and mouse with the Mini.

Comment: I'll look in to a Mac mini, although I'm having far too much trouble figuring out how to code adaptive resolutions. I may never even get a game on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

As you do not own a Mac I can't see how you could manage to do that. Anyway the steps are basically these:

- You (or your client) should enroll for the Apple Development Program
- after that you have to follow the instruction on how to create a certificate with your credential (i.e. private key, etc.)
- then (in the Apple developer page) you have to create an App id for your app
- then (in the Apple developer page) you have to register the ID of your device (i.e. the IPAD, etc.). You can register up to 100 (as far as I remember)
- then you have to create a provisioning for your app (it associate the app Id, to your identity, to your devices).
- then you have to compile the App with XCode, and with the provisioning you have created.

This last step actually requires a MAC